# Is there a reason to use ViewModel in Blazor Server Side?

Tags: architecture, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm starting to develop a Blazor Server Side application and my idea is to use :

- the Features folders structure (see https://medium.com/c2-group/simplifying-projects-with-a-folder-by-feature-structure-3a13cff2d28c)
- the Vertical Slice architecture (see https://jimmybogard.com/vertical-slice-architecture/). In fact, I will use CQRS pattern using MediatR library.

My folders structure will look like this :

```
Features
  Feature 1
     XXXView.razor : the view
     XXXView.razor.cs : the partial class
     XXXView.razor.queries.cs : contains the queries (ex : GetCustomer) used by the view
     XXXView.razor.commands.cs : contains the commands (ex : SaveCustomer) used by the view        
  Feature 2
```

My question is the following : in this kind of architecture, is there a good reason to use a ViewModel (as in asp .net MVC projects) instead of using the entity directly in the view ?
The code below is an example of what I would do without using ViewModel.

```
public partial class UserEditView : EditableComponentBase
{
    [Parameter] 
    public long? Id { get; set; }

    [Required] 
    public string Name { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (this.Id.HasValue)
        {
            UserEntity user = await Mediator.Send(new GetUserQuery(this.Id.Value));
            this.Name = user.Name;
            this.Title = $"Change info of {user.Name}";
        }
        else
        {
            this.Title = "New user";
        }

        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    protected override async Task Save()
    {
        UserEntity user = this.Id.HasValue ? await Mediator.Send(new GetUserEditViewQuery(this.Id.Value)) : new UserEntity();
        user.Nom = this.Name;

        await Mediator.Send(new SaveUserCommand(user));

        Close();
    }
}
```

with GetUserEditViewQuery returning an entity with all information needed fetched or in lazy loading.

The code below is an example of what I would do if I use ViewModel.

```
 public partial class UserEditView : EditableComponentBase
{
    [Parameter] 
    public long? Id { get; set; }

    public UserViewModel User { get; set; } = new UserViewModel();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (this.Id.HasValue)
        {
            this.User = await Mediator.Send(new GetUserEditViewQuery(this.Id.Value));
            this.Title = $"Change info of {this.User.Name}";
        }
        else
        {
            this.Title = "New user";
        }

        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    protected override async Task Save()
    {
        await Mediator.Send(new SaveUserCommand(user));

        Close();
    }
}
```

with GetUserEditViewQuery returning a ViewModel containing all information needed.

As you can see, the differences if I didnt use the ViewModel is that the view :

- define the fields that will be displayed itself (without using a ViewModel)
- get the data using a query which return here an entity (but which could return something else if needed) then use it to set the variables
- convert the variables to an entity (or another object if needed) and call a command to save the information
  => this seems really similar to how I would develop a desktop application

I would be interested by the pros and cons of each approach.

**UPDATE**
@Henk Holterman : I change the GetUserQuery of the example 2 by GetUserEditViewQuery

@Ben Sampica : First, thanks for your answer.
If I understand you correctly,
In a use case "Change user information", the ViewModel (UserEditViewModel) will contain all information needed to edit the user.
In a use case "View user information", the ViewModel (UserViewViewModel : not really nice but ...) will contain all information needed to view the user (which can differ from the change page).
=> the queries are different and so return different ViewModel.

I understood and it makes sense.

But is there only one ViewModel by page or can I use more than one?
Indeed, in some cases, pages contains list with a button which permits the user to add an element in this list.
For me, adding an element in the list will call a new query which add the element in the database then the list is refreshed.

In lot of examples, I see people create a property in the ViewModel of the page (say UserEditViewModel) and populate it in the main query (say GetUserEditViewQuery) which is not really possible here.
If I had to do it, I would certainly do something like this :

```
this.List = await Mediator.Send(new GetListForUserEditViewQuery());
this.User = await Mediator.Send(new GetUserEditViewQuery());
```

Would it be correct ?

Comment: You say "instead of using the entity directly" but that is not in your code. Unless somehow `User == UserViewModel` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the framework of a vertical slice architecture is *having* an architecture. By coupling your domain directly to your presentation, you're opening yourself up for issues when different views need different things. Your `GetUserQuery` shouldn't be that at all, it should be `GetUserEditViewQuery` with the things the view needs - a user, a title, etc. Vertical slicing is about *use cases*, in such case a person needs to view all the editable information about a user.

Your query should return a ViewModel/DTO that represents the use of that view back to the view.

If you can be absolutely positive that such will never be the case - sure, go and use the User directly.